# How to add AWS EC2 load balancer to the same domain as my static frontend

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-route53

I want to add my ec2 load balancer to my domain, under `mysite.com/api/etc`. On route53 it only lets me add a subdomain. In theory I could do `api.mysite.com` but I want to see if `mysite.com/api` is possible first. Currently in my route53 record sets, I just have one for mysite.com and www.mysite.com, (www.mysite.com points to my cloudfront which points to my s3 bucket which redirects to the mysite.com bucket). The reason for all of this is that I want to be able to make https api calls to my ec2 server, but it appears I get a several errors with my current configuration. When I access it via browser, I receive an `ERR_CONNECION_TIMED_OUT`, and when I use python.requests, I get a

```
SSL.ERROR: HTTPSConnectionPool...(Casused by SSLError(CertificatError
("hostname 'my-ec2-env-us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com' 
doesn't match either of 'mysite.com, www.mysite.com)
```

I assume this certificate error is causing my browser timed out error (I'm fairly certain my other configurations are correct, I added my  HTTPS port 443 to security groups with inbound settings to allow 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0, and I selected the 2016-8 SSL Policy. To resolve this certificate error, I assume I need to purchase another domain/add it onto my existing domain, add a certificate to it, and have the endpoint be my EC2 load balancer.

Comment: You can add `LoadBalancer` to `CloudFront` as `Origin`, then create behavior `/api*` or `/api` to route traffic to your api load balancer.

Comment: I see. How do I do that? I added my loadbalancer as my origin domain name, set origin protocol policy to https only, viewer protocol to HTTPS only, whitelisted host for headers, put mysite.com as alternate domain name, but for path pattern I don't see an option to edit/add anything.

Comment: @Tesuji add a *new* Cache Behavior and set the path pattern there.  The default cache behavior should probably point to your bucket.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I see. For my alternate domain name, what do I add there? Am i creating a new cloudfront, or appending to an existing one? The reason I ask is that I cannot put mysite.com as an alternate domain name as it will state that CNAME already exists (I created 2 cloudfronts for each s3 bucket, the www.mysite.com is a redirect to mysite.com)

Comment: You are looking for one CloudFront distribution, with two origins, and two cache behaviors (one pointing to each origin).